# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString appsettings.json in starter

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, appsettings

I am trying to write my connection string in my appsettings.json file and bring it into my startup file but I keep getting a Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString.  I have been using various examples but can't seem to see this new setup with ASP.NET 1.0 Core startup class.

Appsetting.json file:

```
{
"Data": {
"DefaultConnection": {
  "ConnectionString": "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=dbase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

},
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
}
}
}
```

Method attempting
Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        System.Console.WriteLine(connStr);
        services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connStr)); //error right here -- Null value
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First of all, the

```
 "Data": {
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=dbase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"},
}
```

Is slightly different from the structure you get when you add a "Asp.NET Configuration File" in Visual Studio. When you do that you get

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=dbase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"},
```

without the "Data" JavaScript Object. So that's why the extension method isn't working. It expects this structure. You can use this structure (the one with "Data") anyway and get your connection string like so:

```
var connectionString = Configuration["Data:ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
```

Notice that you are navigating through the JavaScript object tree using `:` instead of `.`. That's due to some cross-platform issues with using the `.`.

If you edit out the "Data":{} you can do this :

```
var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
```

Now the extension method will work. Underneath the Microsoft extensions it is the same thing as the code above.

```
var config2 = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

Comment: You keep mentioning "App" but in the Json provided there is no "App", perhaps you mean "Data"? I'm confused.

Comment: You are correct @mastazi, good catch! People have been letting that slide for a couple of years now. I have edited the post.

Comment: Thank you @GlennSills for clarifying that!

Comment: There is a typo in `var connectionString = Configuration["Data::ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];`. The double colon `::` should be replaced by a single colon `:`.

Comment: Thank you! You just saved my life. I spent 2 hours wondering why my connection string for user secrets was not being picked up. Turns out you need to use this exact syntax for it to work: `dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings:<your connection string name> "value"`.

Comment: Make sure your *DbContext* constructor also has: `Configuration = configuration;`

Answer (score 39):

I was missing the letter 's' after the `ConnectionString` property name in the appsettings.json when using `Configuration.GetConnectionString("name")`

[image]

*If you want to copy*

```
"ConnectionStrings ": {
  "SpyStore": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SpyStore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
}
```

The method wording `GetConnectionString` confused me, I hovered over it and oh be hold it was looking for `ConnectionStrings` property name instead of *ConnectionString*

Comment: Just spend half an hour trying different kind of connection strings and this was my problem.... Thanks for the answer

Comment: lol, can't believe that I spent long time trying to figure out what wrong I did, and finally it's one letter missing, thank you Stefan for posting that :)

Answer (score 5):

I had got similar error.My "appsettings.json" file was not loading because the properties of the file was Copy to Output Directory -> Do not Copy. I set that to Copy always save and rebuild.It worked.

Answer (score 4):

`DefaultConnection` is the inner object in the json structure and it is the child of `Data` object.

So if you want to be exact with your config file you can use

```
var connStr = Configuration.GetSection("Data")
                           .GetSection("DefaultConnection")["ConnectionString"];
```

Comment: The GetSection stuff is not required. You can navigate the object tree using a ":' as a delimiter. So Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"] is equivalent. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I got this because I had a connection string with a `\` in it, which needed escaping to be a `\\`. So my localdb connection string was causing a load error like this:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\myinstance;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catlog=my-localdb;"
```

and was fixed by making it:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\myinstance;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catlog=my-localdb;"
```

Answer (score 2):

this is was the message that appeared me

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString

I fix it changed in the startup these lines

```
services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(
Configuration["Data:BookStoreContext:ConnectionString"]));
```

To

```
services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(
Configuration.GetConnectionString("BookStoreContext")));
```

Answer (score 2):

in asp.net core you must add IConfiguration to startUp contractor method and assignee this Parameter to a property inherited from IConfiguration inside class

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the proposed code as text (formatted as a code block). Code posted as an image isn't useful.

Answer (score 2):

my issue is fixed by fixing a typo
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem using asp.net core 3.0.
The workaround fix for me is:

## Instead of:

> var connectionString =
>   Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

## Use this:

> var connectionString =
>   Configuration["ConnectionStrings::DefaultConnection"];

The emphasis here is the double colon in the connection configuration.

Comment: Why the double colon? What is the difference?

Comment: I was still facing the same issue until I found this answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another mistake in my case was that I was using ConnectionString, instead ConnectionStrings (Note last 's')

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection")
);
```

Then set your `appsettings.json` do something like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings:": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=HOME1_DATABASE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

After that, when a I add migration via the console, it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

While using Postgres SQL the appsettings.Development.json must contain

```
"ConnectionStrings": {  
      "DefaultConnection": "User ID=user;Password=xxxx;Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=abc;Pooling=true"
    }
```

Content in the Startup.cs file would be like

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
        (p => p.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to add connection strings into your `appsetting.json` file is the following:

```json
"ConnectionStrings":{
   "DefaultConnection":"Server=localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Datbase=MyShop;Trusted_Connection=true"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- I get it,it was because  the name of connection string that in app settings was difference from that in the configuration that in Startup !!!
- The right code of connection String Configuration in startup

```
// replace NAMEHERE with the name of the class that inherits from DbContext
services.AddDbContextPool <NAMEHERE> (opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("here put the same Connection string name that in appsettings")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I fought with the null connection string issue far too long, only to find I was doing this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MlDataContext>(provider => new MlDataContext(config.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings:SqlConnectionString")));
```

I was using both the `ConnectionStrings:` prefix AND `GetConnectionString`. When I removed the prefix it worked:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MlDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("SqlConnectionString")));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Postgre Db, Below worked for me

```
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    string connectionString;
    public DataBaseContext(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
        connectionString= _config.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:sampleConnection");
    }
```

Config file:

"ConnectionStrings": {
"sampleConnection":".."
}

Start up file:
services.AddScoped();

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two IConfiguration definitions in my Startup class.  Not helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on the day when usin Asp.Net Core 5. I tried all above solutions with no satisfaction. Then I  deleted the "ConnectionStrings" section the appsettings.json file and launched a migration. After the error, I rewrote the  section and launched again the migration. All worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have all you connection strings defined in the app.json.
My problem was I had two different projects that added a dbContext in their services config

1. The identity project which made a reference to the identityDb
2. The persistence project that all my data access logic

I solved the issue by having both connection strings defined in the app.json

Answer (score 0):

try it, it will work for you on version 3.0.0.

public class Startup
{
private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
this.Configuration = configuration;
}

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyPortfolio"));
        });
    }
```

---

appsettings.json

```
{
```

"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Information",
"Microsoft": "Warning",
"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}
},
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
"MyPortfolio": "Data Source=(localdbd)\MSSQLLocalDB; initail catalog=MyPortfolioDB; Integrated Security=true"
}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this fixed it for me:

```
connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

change to:

```
connStr = Configuration["DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same error but realize to be an typo.

```
"ConnectionStringd": {
    "DefaultConnection":  "Server=localhost;Database=BookListRazor;Trusted_Connection=True;MutipleActiveResultSets=True"
},
```

the correct typing should be

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":  "Server=localhost;Database=BookListRazor;Trusted_Connection=True;MutipleActiveResultSets=True"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from YourProjectName.**csproj** file:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is a new deployment to a new server. It turns out the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT was not set, so .NET Core couldn't get the connection string from appsettings.PROD file, and thus passed null to options.UseSqlServer(connection).

Once I created a new environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and set its value to PROD, problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the method given below

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<FullstackAPIcontext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("FullStackConnectionString")));
```

You can directly add the connection string after Usesqlserver .The code snippet is given below

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<FullstackAPIcontext>(options =>
       {
           options.UseSqlServer("Server=myserver;Database=FullstackDb;Trusted_Connection=SSPI;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true");
       });
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your `appsetting.json`to:

```
    {
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=dbase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

    },
    "Logging": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And now will be working:

```
  var connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

Comment: ConnectionString must not be child of Data, as `GetConnectionString('DefaultConnection`) is an shorthand for `Configuration["ConnectionString:DefaultConnection"]`